# MySQL timezone change?

Tags: mysql, timezone

How do I change my timezone which is currently in UTC to GMT +1, what is the correct line and do i just enter it in phpMyAdmin SQL execution?

My host just gave me this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html and went off so I'm kinda lost thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

issue the command:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

(Or whatever time zone GMT+1 is.:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

This is the command to set the MySQL timezone for an individual client, assuming that your clients are spread accross multiple time zones.

This command should be executed before every SQL command involving dates.  If your queries go thru a class, then this is easy to implement.

Comment: This will automatically change the date/time obtained from all the TIMESTAMP fields, but not the DATETIME fields.

Comment: It will not change the values stored in DATETIME or TIMESTAMP fields.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I I get a "Error Code: 1298. Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'America/New_York'
"

Answer (score 44):

The easiest way to do this, as noted by Umar is, for example

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Using the named timezone is important for timezone that has a daylights saving adjustment. However, for some linux builds you may get the following response:

> #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone

If you're seeing this, you may need to run a tzinfo_to_sql translation... it's easy to do, but not obvious. From the linux command line type in:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/|mysql -u root mysql -p
```

Provide your root password (MySQL root, not Linux root) and it will load any definitions in your zoneinfo into mysql. You can then go back and run your

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on centOS 7.1

Comment: What about users on windows getting "#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone"?

Answer (score 27):

While Bryon's answer is helpful, I'd just add that his link is for PHP timezone names, which are not the same as MySQL timezone names.

If you want to set your timezone for an individual session to GMT+1 (UTC+1 to be precise) just use the string '+01:00' in that command. I.e.:

`SET time_zone = '+01:00';`

To see what timezone your MySQL session is using, just execute this:

`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`

This is a great reference with more details: [MySQL 5.5 Reference on Time Zones](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone,@@global.system_time_zone;

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to synchronize PHP (>=5.3) and MySQL timezones per session and user settings. Put this where it runs when you need set and synchronized timezones.

```
date_default_timezone_set($my_timezone);
$n = new \DateTime();
$h = $n->getOffset()/3600;
$i = 60*($h-floor($h));
$offset = sprintf('%+d:%02d', $h, $i);
$this->db->query("SET time_zone='$offset'");
```

Where $my_timezone is one in the list of PHP timezones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

The PHP timezone has to be converted into the hour and minute offset for MySQL. That's what lines 1-4 do.

Comment: Can't you get the same with <?= date('P'); ?>

Answer (score 4):

If you have the SUPER  privilege, you can set the global server time zone value at runtime with this statement:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
```

Comment: And what if there is no superadmin privilege?

Comment: just `SET time_zone = timezone;`

Answer (score 1):

If SET time_zone or SET GLOBAL time_zone does not work, you can change as below:

- Change timezone system, example: ubuntu... $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure
  tzdata
- Restart the server or you can restart apache2 and mysql
  (/etc/init.d/mysql restart)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
<?php
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
      $con->query("SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Calcutta'");
      $con->query("SET time_zone = '+05:30'");
      $con->query("SET @@session.time_zone = '+05:30'");
?>
```