# UNIX_TIMESTAMP no working

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

In my database, I have the record: **'2013-01-24 16:40:08'**

Using the function **strtotime** on PHP, I get the timestamp **1359045608**.

Executing the query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_timestamp_column) FROM my_table WHERE my_id_column = my_id
```

I get the timestamp **1359056408** and not the timestamp **1359045608**.

Converting **1359056408**, I get **'2013-01-24 19:40:08'**, why!?

Comment: It'll be timezone differences ...

Comment: @martin clayton Where I configure?

Comment: There is no way this question is worth **2** upvotes.

Comment: How about just storing everything in GMT/UTC?

Comment: In my database, I use GMT - 3, but, using the function UNIX_TIMESTAMP, the database get the value in GMT.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_timestamp_column) + TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NOW())
FROM my_table
WHERE my_id_column = my_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect they're set to different timezones.

Compare your MySQL time with your PHP system time:

```
  SELECT NOW();
```

vs.

```
  <?php
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       echo $date;
```

they'll probably be 2 hours off.

Comment: SELECT NOW(); = 2013-01-24 17:21:12, but... SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-24 17:21:12') = 1359058872, Converting 1359058872 = 2013-01-24 20:21:12

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're converting the timestamp back to the date in PHP.

Look at the difference in the timestamps: `1359056408` - `1359045608` = `10800`.

Now divide that by `60` seconds/minute and `60` minutes/hour:

```
10800 / 60 = 180
180 / 60 = 3
```

That means you are in a time zone that is off by 3 hours from the UTC time.
You should use a function(s) that can generate timestamp in the UTC or (if that is the case) you should use a date-time storage format that is "aware" or immune to the time locality issues.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this timestamp? Do you want to display it? Be aware that your PHP and MySQL servers *both* have to be correctly set up to the same time zone. Otherwise you'll always get some discrepancies between both PHP and DB timestamps.

Comment: I need that the timestamp generated by the PHP is equal to timestamp generated by the unix_timestamp function on MySQL. Where i can configure the timezones?

Comment: That depends on what server have you access to. In case it's PHP - see the answer by PoX. In case it's DB - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10251943/1820695

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GMT on your database you can set php to use same timezone by setting 
`date.timezone` in php see [date.timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php) This way `strtotime` should use specified time zone.