# Want to get times according to my time zone not the servers time zone

Tags: php

I'm from India. Hosting my site in 000webhost. I'm tracking the IPs visiting and their times. but the time is wrong i.e I think times are according to the time zone of 000webhost server. How to convert them according to Indian timezone.

this is the code I am using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$query="INSERT INTO visitor_ip ";
$query.="VALUES('{$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]}',now())";
```

Comment: Also the [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is timezone independent so all of your conversions could take place at run time and you can use this as the backbone.

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve it is running an SQL query first which sets the MySQL connection time zone: `SET time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';`. More info here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html
- [MySQL timezone change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451847/mysql-timezone-change)
- [MySQL Time Zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808160/mysql-time-zones)

Another way to solve it is using PHP date and time functions (outside quotes) instead of `NOW()` (inside quotes) to query the time as a string, and passing that string to MySQL. `date_default_timezone_set` will affect the PHP date and time functions.

Comment: I'm using date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); In php.net it says after this function all function related to time date will use this time zone. Then why its not happening

Comment: @Jayadratha Mondal: `date_default_timezone_set` affects only the PHP time zone, and `NOW()` uses the MySQL time zone. That's why it doesn't work the way you tried it.

Comment: Thanks for informing this. So Can I use this??

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time=date("Y-m-d / h-i-s A",time());
$query="INSERT INTO visitor_ip ";
$query.="VALUES('{$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]}',$time)";