# Linux Server how to change TimeZone permenantly

Tags: java, mysql, linux, timezone

1. I am changing the time zone by tzselect but on logout this time zone changes to default one. How to make this change permanently ?
2. Server time zone should also reflect on the mysql time zone. How to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am changing the time zone by tzselect but on logout this time zone changes to default one. How to make this change permanently ?

Follow these steps:

```
$ date
Fri Dec 20 09:42:24 UTC 2013

$ rm -rf /etc/localtime

$ ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific /etc/localtime

$ date
Fri Dec 20 01:43:19 PST 2013
```

The point is, you need to use the use the required zoneinfo file located under `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`

> Server time zone should also reflect on the mysql time zone. How to do this ?

I could not interpret above statement properly. But seems like you should be using NTP so that Time across all the servers will be same.

Comment: How to change the mysql server default time zone and change should also be permenant?

Comment: for MySQL, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) and [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/how-to-change-mysql-server-time-zone) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451847/mysql-timezone-change)

Answer (score 0):

After changing the timezone with `tzselect` take a look at the UTC settings in `/etc/default/rcS`. Also go through [this article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/25), you might find it **very** useful.

Cheers!