# MySQL Wrong timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

My MySQL database is saving the time users register on my website using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. THe thing is that it is the hosts timezone which is completely different from the one the website is used in. Is there any way to change the timezone in MySQL?

Comment: You are looking in the wrong direction... And yes there is a way, but it involves changing the timezone of your server..

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL timezone change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451847/mysql-timezone-change)

Comment: Try saving time stamp in  UTC form, that might help..

Comment: use this `SET time_zone = timezonename;`

Answer (score 1):

To set a value for it use either one:

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
```