# Mysql Giving me incorrect time

Tags: php, mysql

When i am running a query with NOW(), it gives me incorrect time (Actual Time+4 Hours).

```
"SELECT NOW() AS current_time ";
```

The above is the simple query.

Comment: Its because your timezone will be different for Mysql or in php.ini file.
If its the live server then check the default timezone of your server.

Comment: The code is working in Localhost, i will contact my server providers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL timezone change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451847/mysql-timezone-change)

Comment: Check `SELECT @@session.time_zone` and `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP)`. PHP's timezone and MySQL's session timezone can be changed at runtime, the provider may or may not have anything to do with it.

Comment: i tried
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) giving me the below output  -04:00:00

Comment: any idea about the issue?

Comment: you have to check your server timezone, if you want your timezone time then you have to change timezone of server based on your location